# Ruby sorting and eliminating duplicates

Tags: ruby, arrays, list, sorting, methods

I have a list that I need to sort by the most popular elements. Is there a method to accomplish that?

After I re-sort it, I also need to get rid of duplicates. I have an idea of a function in my mind for this but it seems inefficient, so are there built-in methods to help with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[1,5,4,6,4,1,4,5].group_by {|x| x}.sort_by {|x,list| [-list.size,x]}.map(&:first)
=> [4,1,5,6]
```

Like that?

Answer (score 3):

The [`Array#sort`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Array.html#method-i-sort) method takes an optional predicate to compare two elements, so...

```
list.sort { |a, b| a.popularity <=> b.popularity }
```

To eliminate duplicates, use [`Array#uniq`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Array.html#method-i-uniq).

```
list.uniq
```

To glue them together,

```
list = list.sort { |a, b| a.popularity <=> b.popularity }.unique
```

Or simply

```
list.sort! { |a, b| a.popularity <=> b.popularity }.uniq!
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterating through the list to build a hash that maps `item -> number of times` just need one visit of all elements of the list, then operations with the hash would be constant time, so O(n), that doesn't seem so expensive.

Answer (score 0):

The uniq method takes a block, so you can specify which 'property' of your object has to be uniq.

```
new_list = list.sort_by{|el| el.popularity}.uniq{|el| el.popularity}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of these answers didn't work for me, except for Glenn Mcdonalds (up until i posted this answer)
I found an answer to my own question somewhere  else like this

```
list = [2,1,4,4,4,1] #for example
count = Hash.new(0)
list.each {|element| count[element] += 1} #or some other parameter than element
list = list.uniq.sort {|x,y| count[y] <=> count[x]}
```